# How to click different parts of the image and be directed to different destinations?

Tags: html, css

I have a png image, it's a map, it represents 4 countries : france, italy, spain and germany, what I need to do, is to use CSS to devided and by passing cursor on each zone, i'll have a popup with name of every country.

Div doesn't need to be with exact shapes of every country.

Any idea how to put div for each zone inside this image please ?

For now i'm trying this :

```
container{
   width : 100px;
   height : 100px;
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

and the HTML is :

```
<div class = "container"><img src="src/assets/img_map.png"/></div>
```

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Same question you posted few minutes ago

Comment: @Vishnu I was thinking of triming the image, i'll update my question again

Comment: It isn't possible. Just use 4 images and combine them to appear single image and use hover effect on images

Comment: you would put images inside divs, not the other way around :)

Comment: @Sushi Okay.. update with code

Comment: Why not position transparent divs absolute above the image?

Comment: look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1201052/6191987

Answer (score 2):

**Create hotspot/imagemap on image**

An imagemap is a graphic image where a user can click on different parts of the image and be directed to different destinations. imagemaps are made by defining each of the hot areas in terms of their x and y coordinates (relative to the top left hand corner). With each set of coordinates, you specify a link that users will be directed to when they click within the area.

[Image map generator link](https://www.image-map.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/np72xv2s/  click the first box on the image

Answer (score 1):

Use an imagemap (html Elements `map` and `area`) and do the necessary highlighting via JavaScript.

Or do a `position: relative` on your container and add your divs with `position: absolute` inside the container.